# CSS Selector to target Data attribute

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML line:

```html
<div data-component-id="12345" class="component" data-component-status="operational">
```

Is it possible to use the `data-component-id` as a CSS Selector?

I would like to add a CSS code especially for this div, eg: `{display: none}`

Comment: It's called [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp): `div[data-component-id="12345"] {}`

Comment: Also you can read [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) aboutn attribute selector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute selector `[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for this

```css
div[data-component-id="12345"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-component-id="12345" class="component" data-component-status="operational">
  Demo
</div>
```